# Killing "System Error" dialog box under csrss.exe

Tags: windows, testing, dll, csrss

I'm running an automated test of an application that has insufficient dependencies (missing dll), and got this error message:

[image: The program can't start because CUDAPhysicalSystem.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.]

When the test runner kills the application, the above message box isn't disappearing. Apparently it's owned by csrss.exe, which can't be killed.

My problem is that the only way I can get this message box to close is by manually logging in to to the machine and clicking the X on that message window. Is there another way?

Note that I can easily fix the dependency error, but I would like a robust way of terminating the application under test with all its messages when such errors are encountered.

Answer (score 3):

Try avoiding the dialog in the first place: Call `SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS)` in your test runner, this will cause calls to `CreateProcess` to fail silently if the loader cannot resolve every import.

If you want to create a query function so you can tell if the process can load, add the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag when calling `CreateProcess` and call `TerminateProcess` if it succeeded.

Comment: yes, the `SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS)` is good solution. but use `CREATE_SUSPENDED` here no sense - in any case, if application path correct and point to valid exe file - `CreateProcess` return *TRUE* even if some dependencies dlls missing. for determinate this - we can wait process exit and call `GetExitCodeProcess` - in case dll missing will be `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND` exit code. of course this exit code can be and in some another case too.

Comment: Debugging the process is probably better if you don't actually want to execute the application, if it gets to the entrypoint function or TLS callback everything is OK.

Comment: Debugging - yes, this is also possible and not hard. even until process exit. with this also can log different errors. however most simply solution for suppress hard error - how you suggest -  `SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS)`

Answer (score 1):

you can do next:

1) get *csrss.exe* process id in your session

2) enumerate windows via [`EnumWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx), for every window query it process id ([`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx)), compare it with *csrss.exe* process id. if equal - get window class name ([`GetClassName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582(v=vs.85).aspx) ) and if it is `L"#32770"` - post [`WM_CLOSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617(v=vs.85).aspx) message to this window

3) if you want be more precise - after you found `L"#32770"` window class, query the window caption text via [`GetWindowText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx) and ensure that it begin with `"module.exe - "` or how your exe is named ?

```
struct FIND_WND_CONTEXT 
{
    PCWSTR szCaptionBegin;
    ULONG lenCaptionBegin;
    ULONG dwProcessId;
};

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWndProc(HWND hwnd, FIND_WND_CONTEXT& fwc)
{
    ULONG dwProcessId;
    if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwProcessId) && dwProcessId == fwc.dwProcessId)
    {
        PWSTR Name = (PWSTR)alloca( max(fwc.lenCaptionBegin * sizeof(WCHAR), sizeof(L"#32770") + sizeof(WCHAR)) );

        if (GetClassNameW(hwnd, Name, sizeof(L"#32770") + sizeof(WCHAR)) && !wcscmp(Name, L"#32770"))
        {
            if (GetWindowText(hwnd, Name, fwc.lenCaptionBegin))
            {
                _wcslwr(Name);
                if (!wcscmp(Name, fwc.szCaptionBegin))
                {
                    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}

void CloseTest()
{
    const WCHAR module_exe[] = L"module.exe - ";
    FIND_WND_CONTEXT fwc = { module_exe, RTL_NUMBER_OF(module_exe) };

    if (fwc.dwProcessId = GetMySessionCsrssId())
    {
        EnumWindows((WNDENUMPROC)EnumWndProc, (LPARAM)&fwc);
    }
}

ULONG GetMySessionCsrssId()
{
    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 0x10000;
    static volatile UCHAR guz;
    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PBYTE pb;
        PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi;
    };

    ULONG SessionId;
    ProcessIdToSessionId(GetCurrentProcessId(), &SessionId);

    NTSTATUS status;
    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        if (0 <= (status = ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, buf, cb, &rcb)))
        {
            ULONG NextEntryOffset = 0;
            do 
            {
                pb += NextEntryOffset;

                STATIC_UNICODE_STRING(csrss, "csrss.exe");

                if (pspi->SessionId == SessionId && RtlEqualUnicodeString(&pspi->ImageName, &csrss, TRUE))
                {
                    return PtrToUlong(pspi->UniqueProcessId);
                }

            } while (NextEntryOffset = pspi->NextEntryOffset);

            return 0;
        }

    } while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);

    return 0;
}
```

somebody of course ask - why use "undocumented", ("no longer available" (this is direct lie in msdn - available from win200 to latest win10 1703), "unsupported", etc) [`ZwQuerySystemInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725506(v=vs.85).aspx) with `SystemProcessInformation` instead `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` + `Process32First` + `Process32Next` ? because we need got `SessionId` information for process. the [`SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntexapi_8h_source.html#l01525) containing `ULONG SessionId` member, while psapi shell over this function by unknown reason drop this member - [`PROCESSENTRY32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839(v=vs.85).aspx) - no here `SessionId` - it dropped. of course we can retrieve `SessionId` by addition call to [`ProcessIdToSessionId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382990(v=vs.85).aspx), but this function internally open process by Id, for query it SessionId. but for open `csrss.exe` you need *SeDebugPriviledge* enabled in your toke (+ 3 extra call to kernel - open process, query information, close handle)